# Ubuntu not detecting wifi after sleep

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi

I had recently dual booted Ubuntu (latest version) with windows 11 on my laptop. But everytime I put it on sleep and get it back on, it does not show any available wifi networks, and sometimes even the option of wifi disappears.
I have tried to restart the NetworkManager service but it didn't work. When i booted windows, and then switched to Ubuntu, the wifi started working, but the problem continues after sleep.

Comment: any indication of issues in your system logs?

Comment: You should search again, specifying your WiFi adapter (or at least the kernel module used). Some cards do so, and there are several work-arounds. Look for your specific adapter

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.